# GeoTools - How to do Dead Reckoning and course calculations using GeoTools classes

Tags: java, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geotools, dead-reckoning

I'm currently using the GeoTools toolkit to do calculations on marine vessel data, such as calculating the Great Circle distance between two lon/lat points. I have two other requirements that I need to satisfy, but I'm not sure where to look in GeoTools to find classes to do these kind of calculations.

**REQUIREMENT #1:**
Calculate a [Dead Reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) position for a moving vessel.

INPUT VALUES:

- current longitude
- current latitude
- current speed (which can be easily converted to a distance, given a time 'T')
- current course

EXPECTED OUTPUTS:

- estimated longitude/latitude position after time 'T' has elapsed

**REQUIREMENT #2:**
Calculate the course from position 'A' to position 'B'.

INPUT VALUES:

- longitude 'A'
- latitude 'A'
- longitude 'B'
- latitude 'B'

EXPECTED OUTPUTS:

- course that points directly from 'A' to 'B'

**QUESTION**

**Can anyone direct me to classes in GeoTools that are capable of performing these calculations? I'm overwhelmed by the sheer number of classes in GeoTools and I can't seem to find what I need to do this.**

Comment: If not this page has all the math you need http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs

Comment: @RomainHippeau Funny you say that. Someone at my company already spent some time manually re-implementing part of that JavaScript code into a Java class. Ideally though, we would rather stick with a properly maintained open source library for all of this stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HOW TO CALCULATE COURSE FROM POSITION 'A' TO POSITION 'B'**

- Need to have the lat/lon of positions 'A' and 'B'
- Get an instance of the `GeodeticCalculator` class
- Call `setStartingGeographicPoint()`
- Call `setDestinationGeographicPoint()`
- Call `getAzimuth()`
- Convert from azimuth to decimal degrees

**HOW TO CALCULATE DEAD RECKONING POSITION 'X' STARTING FROM POSITION 'A'**

- Need to have the lat/lon of position 'A'
- Need to have the current course of the vessel in azimuth
- Need to have the distance to travel in meters (or calculate this as speed * time)
- Get an instance of the `GeodeticCalculator` class
- Call `setStartingGeographicPoint()`
- Call `setDirection()`
- Call `getDestinationGeographicPoint()`

Here are some simple units conversion methods that I needed to implement myself. The azimuth was a little confusing. The azimuth ranges from -180 to +180 with the values increasing as the direction "angle" increases in a clockwise direction. So -180 is south, -90 is west, 0 is true north, +90 is east and +180 is also south.

```
public static final double KNOTS_PER_MPS = 1.9438444924406;
public static final double MPS_PER_KNOT = 0.514444444444444;


public static double metersPerSecondToKnots(double speedInMetersPerSecond) {
    return speedInMetersPerSecond * KNOTS_PER_MPS;
}

public static double knotsToMetersPerSecond(double speedInKnots) {
    return speedInKnots * MPS_PER_KNOT;
}

public static double courseInDegreesToAzimuth(double courseInDegrees) {
    Validate.isTrue(courseInDegrees >= 0.0 && courseInDegrees <= 360.0);
    double azimuth;
    if (courseInDegrees > 180.0) {
        azimuth = -180.0 + (courseInDegrees - 180.0);
    } else {
        azimuth = courseInDegrees;
    }
    return azimuth;
}

public static double azimuthToCourseInDegrees(double azimuth) {
    Validate.isTrue(azimuth >= -180.0 && azimuth <= 180.0);
    double courseInDegrees;
    if (azimuth < 0.0) {
        courseInDegrees = 360.0 + azimuth;
    } else {
        courseInDegrees = azimuth;
    }
    return courseInDegrees;
}
```