# How to calculate current position lat/long based on previously kown lat/long

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

I have a requirement to calculate the lat and long values of the current position of the user. However, I can't use GPS/Network. I know a previous lat long location of the user. This previous location has been queried from the GPS provider. After this initial location is found, GPS is no more available. User travels a certain distance from this point and in certain direction. Both these values, distance and direction of travel (in terms of angle), are known. Is there any way that I can arrive at the new lat/long coordinates based on this available information (previous lat/long coordinates, distance & direction traveled from the previous position).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link [GeoTools - How to do Dead Reckoning and course calculations using GeoTools classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917340/geotools-how-to-do-dead-reckoning-and-course-calculations-using-geotools-class) answers my question. Given an angle, distance and starting geographic point, [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) (java) can be used to do the calculation. Refer to the SO link to see the sample.

Answer (score 2):

This method of navigation is known as [dead reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning): Given is an initial position, the task is to deduce the current position from known information, e.g. heading, time travelled, and speed (or heading and distance).
You may find some formulas to compote the new location [here](http://www.efalk.org/Navigation/math.html).

Answer (score 1):

Stefan gives you a good place to start. However, depending on what you want to do with that information, you might be better to use a [Kalman Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), which would allow you to account for error in both the starting position, distance traveled and direction traveled. This is especially true if the user is isn't moving just once, but several times.

Comment: MC, have not looked at Kalman filter yet. But will check it out. Thanks